# Detect a colour based on its RGB

Tags: colors, computer-vision, rgb, tracking.js

I want to detect red and green objects from webcam. I am using this [Trackingjs](http://trackingjs.com/) library. I think with the library, it will track the red, green and blue value of an object and detect the colour according to the built-in colour library in their code.

Their built-in colours are defined like this:

```
  tracking.ColorTracker.registerColor('purple', function(r, g, b) {
    var dx = r - 120;
    var dy = g - 60;
    var dz = b - 210;
    if ((b - g) >= 100 && (r - g) >= 60) {
      return true;
    }
    return dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz < 3500;
  });
```

In the example above, objects which has their `blue - green >= 100` and `red -green >= 60` will be `purple`.

Can someone explain this to me how this works. 
And if I want to detect red/ reddish and green/greenish, how should I do with the same function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the colour RGB(120,60,210) it is this purple:

[image]

Now, `dx` measures the distance that the passed in colour is from the red component in that purple, `dy` measures the distance that the passed in colour is from the green component of that purple and `dz` measures the distance that the passed in colour is from the blue component.

The return value at the end, calculates, using 3-D Pythagorus, the square of the distance that the passed in colour is from purple in the 3-D colour cube with black at one corner, white diagonally opposite and R, G and B at the corners. So, it effectively defines a *"sphere"* of colour around the purple.

If you want to detect reddish tones, you will want something like

```
if ((r-g)>50 && (r-b)>50) { return true;}
```

which just says you want there to be more red than green and more red than blue.

If you want to detect greenish tones, you will want something like

```
if ((g-r)>50 && (g-b)>50) { return true;}
```

which just says you want there to be more green than red and more green than blue.

Comment: This is very good knowledge to know. The red works properly but with the green.
My green I want to detect is from cucumber, which is dark green.
When I tried the code for green, it detects more light green, as it only detects the parts that has light reflection on the cucumber. Do you have any suggestion? My code at the moment for the green is:       `if ((g-r) >= 50 && (g-b)>=10) 
      {
        return true;
      }`

Comment: Depending on what OS you use, you can use a "Digital Color Meter" program to inspect the RGB values you are trying to detect and then devise a formula that detects it... http://innolea.com/easily-detect-rgb-and-html-hex-code-of-colors/2308 Or maybe you just need `&& g < 64` to only find dark greens. Or maybe you need to convert to HSL colorspace and look for hues around 0.3.

Answer (score 0):

[RGB Colour Parser.](https://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/)
this is what you need. And of course it can be used for color verification.

From the description:

A JavaScript class that accepts a string and tries to figure out a valid color out of it. Some accepted inputs are for example:

```
rgb(0, 23, 255)
#336699
ffee66
fb0
red
darkblue
cadet blue
```

DEMO: [Demo](https://www.phpied.com/files/rgbcolor/rgbcolor.html)