# Why it doesn't show the bluish in blue majority?

Tags: javascript, html

So I was creating an app in which I would click on a button and it would generate a color with its details in JavaScript (vanilla), details are given in a `<h1>` tag.

One of the details is telling if the thing is red, green or blue majority. The website functions properly, but there's a bug.

When there is a blue majority, it shows red or green. How can I fix it?

```js
//main func
document.getElementById('rand').onclick = () => {
  //randing the no.
  red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);


  //now, setting it up
  document.body.style.background = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
  color.textContent = `color = ${red}, ${green}, ${blue} (in rgb context)`;
  color.style.color = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
  switch (red, green, blue) {
    case red > green && blue:
      color.textContent += "(reddish)";
      break;
    case green > red && blue:
      color.textContent += "(greenish)";
      break;
    case blue > green && red:
      color.textContent += "(bluish)";
      break;
    default:
      color.textContent += "(blank)";
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="interfaceMain">
    <h1 id="color">Default</h1>
    <button id="rand">Randomise</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. What are `start` and `color`?

Comment: Also this is not how you compare one value against multiple others: `red > green&&blue` -> `red > green && red > blue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) properly. Also, the `start` and `color` identifiers are undefined in your code.

So, I have modified your code by replacing the button id with `start` to run the code. Also the logic of `switch statement` is replaced with `if-else statement` with the proper use of `AND` operator.

**The logic behind the approach ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33937399/8188682)):**

when Red: `red - green > 50 && red - blue > 50` is `true`

When Green: `green - red > 50 && green - blue > 50` is `true`

When Blue: `blue - green > 50 && blue - red > 50` is `true`

Check the following example code:

```js
//main func
const color = document.querySelector('#color');
const start = document.querySelector('#start');
start.onclick = () => {
  //randing the no.
  red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);


  //now, setting it up
  document.body.style.background = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
  color.textContent = `color = ${red}, ${green}, ${blue} (in rgb context)`;
  color.style.color = `white`;
 
   if(red - green > 50 && red - blue > 50){
        color.textContent += "(reddish)";
      }
      else if(green - red > 50 && green - blue > 50){
        color.textContent += "(greenish)";
      }
      else if(blue - green > 50 && blue - red > 50){
        color.textContent += "(bluish)";
      }
      else {
        color.textContent += "(blank)";
      }
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="interfaceMain">
    <h1 id="color">Default</h1>
    <button id="start">Randomise</button>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where did you find that criteria: difference between "color A" and "color B" has to be `> 50`

Comment: _"I have modified your code by replacing the button id with start to run the code."_ - Why the usage of a non-standard behavior introduced by IE instead of `.querySelector()` like you're doing for `#color`?

Comment: I have updated it in my answer, please check

Comment: The only actual problem with OPs code is the invalid comparison of multiple values. There are already multiple questions with that exact same problem hence this question should be closed as duplicate of ... or "just a typo"